# FullCalendar MVC areas modul Build:Cannot find module 'moment' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, es6-modules, fullcalendar-4

In the project I have done, when I add the files of the FullCalendar plugin and build the project, it gives the following error.

```
Error :
Build:Cannot find module 'luxon' or its corresponding type declarations.
Build:Cannot find module 'moment' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

When I go to the error in the Erors window, it redirects to the code below.

Code:

```
// Generated by dts-bundle v0.7.3-fork.1
// Dependencies for this module:
// ../../../../../luxon
// ../../../../../@fullcalendar/core

declare module '@fullcalendar/luxon' {
    import { DateTime as LuxonDateTime, Duration as LuxonDuration } from 'luxon';
    import { Calendar, Duration } from '@fullcalendar/core';
    export function toDateTime(date: Date, calendar: Calendar): LuxonDateTime;
    export function toDuration(duration: Duration, calendar: Calendar): LuxonDuration;
    const _default: import("@fullcalendar/core").PluginDef;
    export default _default;
}
```

In the system structure there is `_LayoutAdmin.cshtml` under the home directory.

There are codes on the site that I will add under the patches structure.

I could not solve the error and the problem somehow. can you help me

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json`, if any. Are you using NPM?

Comment: I added the zip files to my project. There is no file named tsconfig.json